# how can i open another window in tkinter from another file?

Tags: python, tkinter

i have a problem in my code in python (tkinter) I have two files (ger_dentista.py) and (ger_paciente.py), each is a window, and I have another file called (main.py) that opens a window with two buttons, I want to click one of the (ger_dentista) files every time Or (ger_paciente) open. the window only opens one time, I'm using linux.

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk



root =  Tk()

class funcoes():


def janela2(self):
    import ger_dentista
    

def janela3(self):
    import ger_pacientes


class application(funcoes):


def __init__(self):
    self.root = root
    self.tela()
    self.frames_da_tela()
    self.widgets_frame()
    root.mainloop()

def tela(self):
    self.root.title('ODONTO DIGITAL')
    self.root.configure(background='#483D8B')
    self.root.geometry('800x600')
    self.root.resizable(True, True)
    self.root.minsize(width=600, height=480)

def frames_da_tela(self):
    self.frame_1 = Frame(self.root)
    self.frame_1.place(relx= 0.25, rely= 0.25, relwidth= 0.50, relheight= 0.46)

def widgets_frame(self):
    self.bt_dentista = Button(self.frame_1, text='Gerenciar dentistas', command=self.janela2)
    self.bt_dentista.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.21, relwidth=0.35, relheight=0.12)
    
    self.bt_paciente = Button(self.frame_1, text='Gerenciar pacientes', command=self.janela3)
    self.bt_paciente.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.34, relwidth=0.35, relheight=0.12)
    
    self.bt_consulta = Button(self.frame_1, text='Gerenciar Consultas')
    self.bt_consulta.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.48, relwidth=0.35, relheight=0.12)

    self.bt_sair = Button(self.frame_1, text='Sair')
    self.bt_sair.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.62, relwidth=0.35, relheight=0.12)   

    self.lb_pesquisar = Label(self.frame_1, text='O que deseja fazer?')
    self.lb_pesquisar.place(relx=0.32 , rely=0.04)

application()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `os` module to open another script.

Example:

```
import os

os.startfile('C:/Users/my/Desktop/programming/tkinter/app.py')
#put in brackets your location to script, above location is just to demonstrate
```

And little coment to your code:

dont use `from tkinter import *`, use for example `import tkinter as tk` and if you need widget or something you can use for example `from tkinter import Button`

Comment: Did you notice that OP has stated in the question: *"I'm using linux"*?  `os.startfile()` is Windows only.